# Identity - user rights in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm creating a web application where a user that is logged in via Identity can create new objects (products) for sale. However I wonder how can I use Identity to make it so that a user can only see their own created objects. I've been thinking about `UserManager` but I'm fairly new to this so I'm not really sure where to start.

If anyone can show me a pretty simple way to solve this I would appreciate it a lot. Been reading a lot of Microsoft's documentation but I don't feel like I'm getting much wiser.

This is my `InventoryController` where I manage my "Products":

```
using auktioner_MarcusR91.Data;
using auktioner_MarcusR91.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace auktioner_MarcusR91.Controllers
{
    public class InventoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public InventoryController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Inventory> objInventoryList = _db.Inventories;
            return View(objInventoryList);
        }

        //GET
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //Post
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Inventory inventory)
        {
            _db.Inventories.Add(inventory);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }

        //GET
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == 0 || id == 5) 
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var inventoryFromDb = _db.Inventories.Find(id);

            if (inventoryFromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(inventoryFromDb);
        }

        //Post
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Inventories.Update(inventory);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }

            return View(inventory);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my create view if that helps:

```
@model Inventory

<form method = "post">
    <div class = "border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class = "row pb-2">
            <h2 class = "text-primary">Add to Inventory</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class = "mb-3">
            <label asp-for ="inventoryName"></label>
            <input asp-for = "inventoryName" />
            <label asp-for ="finalPrize"></label>
            <input asp-for = "finalPrize" />
            <label asp-for ="inventoryDesc"></label>
            <input asp-for = "inventoryDesc" />
            <p>1 för "Transport</p>
            <p>2 för "Smycken"</p>
            <p>3 för "Hushåll"</p>
            <p>4 för "Dekoration"</p>
            <select asp-for = "categoryId">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" width = "100px">Submit</button>
        <a asp-controller = "Inventory" asp-action = "index" class = "btn btn-secondary" style = "width: 100px">Back to products</a> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

U should use userManager for userId.

```
private readonly AppDbContext _db;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public InventoryController(AppDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
   _db = db;
   _userManager = userManager;
}
```

Then change your query filter by userId.

```
var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
IEnumerable<Inventory> objInventoryList = _db.Inventories.Where(d => d.userId == userId);
```

Comment: Do i need to install package ```Fluent.Infrastructure``` For this? Viusal studio tells me to install it but i have never heard of it

Comment: Where showed requiring `Fluent.Infrastructure`? For asp.net core identity, it seems no requiring this package. The `UserManager` mentioned in the answer requires `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, did you install it?